# Graph API fails for Archive mailboxes

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I've been using the Microsoft Graph API to access Exchange Online (Office365) In-Place Archives.

It's basically an authenticated GET HTTPS request against `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/user@company.onmicrosoft.com/mailFolders/ArchiveMsgFolderRoot` and it used to work fine.

Starting this week (end of April 2020), the same request against the same resource (no change) started failing with:

*404 Response: `{'error': {'code': 'ErrorInvalidMailboxItemId', 'message': "Item Id doesn't belong to the current mailbox.", 'innerError': {'request-id': '4a339242-9821-42a9-9622-4b1f7cd2c162', 'date': '2020-04-24T10:01:35'}}}`*

Other mailboxes (not `ArchiveMsgFolderRoot`) continue to work fine, no problem there. Only In-Place archives are affected.

**How do you access In-places Archives from the Graph API now? Can you share an example?**

Comment: Hi @user124114, I see the functionality is still not available in Graph. Did you perhaps find a work around for this?

Answer (score 3):

Same here. We are trying to figure out what exactly changed on MS side.
MS removed support for In-Place Archives in API. All options on the internet are not working anymore. We are implementing a workaround.

Answer (score 2):

Support of ArchiveMsgFolderRoot was never an official feature. There was an announcement that archiving is going be changing coming time.

Comment: Any idea how to access them now? What announcement?

Comment: I know that after this post https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/compliance/unlimited-archiving?view=o365-worldwide . Our functionality stopped working.