Using MS Graph API to create a new folder by path
I am not sure if this is even possible but if I were to know the path of some premade folders such as "Online Archive/Inbox/TestParentFolder/" and I wanted to create a new folder inside TestParentFolder.How would I go about doing this with ms graph api in c#? Also not sure if its important but these subfolders/path are in the Online Archive as indicated in the path above but from my research that is handled similar to any other folder.
I am able to create folders in the main directory using the following:
        public async Task<Models.Folder> CreateArchiveFolderAsync(string mailbox, string stateAbbreviation, string folderName)
    {
        var requestBody = new MailFolder
        {
            DisplayName = folderName,
            IsHidden = false,
        };

        // To initialize your graphClient, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/create-client?from=snippets&tabs=csharp
        var result = await _graphServiceClient!.Users[mailbox].MailFolders.PostAsync(requestBody);

        return new Models.Folder() {
            Id = result.Id
        };
    }


The Online Archive isn't currently supported in the Microsoft Graph only the primary Mailbox store. It maybe supported in the future but that last update was https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/exchange-team-blog/retirement-of-exchange-web-services-in-exchange-online/ba-p/3924440

This post says you can unless in place archive is a different thing? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52991085/how-to-get-messages-from-archived-mailbox-using-ms-graph-api

Have a read of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61410458/graph-api-fails-for-archive-mailboxes , it was a bug at the time and nolonger works AFAIK since 2020 you can test it yourself in the Graph Explorer (you get a specific error message)

Oh that’s no good lol.

You can't get mailFolder by path. You need to go from the root mailFolder to the last subfolder in the path to get the mailFolder id.
Then use it's id as the parentFolderId when creating a new folder inside it.
Should be quite easy with Graph SDK v5.
private async Task CreateMailSubfolder(GraphServiceClient graphServiceClient, string mailBox, string mailFolderPath, string mailFolderName)
{
    // split mail folders
    var mailFolders = mailFolderPath.Split('/');
    var parentFolderId = string.Empty;
    foreach (var mailFolder in mailFolders)
    {
        // get root mail folder id
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(parentFolderId))
        {
            var folder = await graphServiceClient.Users[mailbox].MailFolders.GetAsync(rc =>
            {
                rc.QueryParameters.Filter = $"displayName eq '{mailFolder}'";
            });
            parentFolderId = folder.Value[0].Id;
        }
        else
        {
            // get subfolder id
            var folder = await graphServiceClient.Users[mailbox].MailFolders[parentFolderId].ChildFolders.GetAsync(rc =>
            {
                rc.QueryParameters.Filter = $"displayName eq '{mailFolder}'";
            });
            parentFolderId = folder.Value[0].Id;
        }
    }

    // create new subfolder
    var newMailFolder = await graphServiceClient.Users[mailbox].MailFolders[parentFolderId].ChildFolders.PostAsync(new MailFolder
    {
        ParentFolderId = parentFolderId,
        DisplayName = mailFolderName
    });
}


Although I am learning you cannot use this on an archive folder this is exactly what I am looking for

Any issues you could see from this solution by modifying it that if at any point the folder doesnt exist in the path it creates that folder? Onedrive works like that when you save a file by path and I was considering something similar in outlook. I also have moved away from using the archive folder for the reasons noted in a comment above.
